# {0}: Conversion error occurred (in SelectOneMenu)

Tags: jsf

I have the following problem - I have a SelectOneMenu, first item is just an information to ask the user to select item from the drop item menu and after that are the real values. I have a Converter which work properly when i select and element from the drop down, but when the user does not select anything i jot this error **{0}: Conversion error occurred**.

Here is the logic for selectOneMenu:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{requestBean.selectedEventType}"
        converter="tEventTypeConverter" 
        required="true" requiredMessage="Please, select item!">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Избери тип" itemvalue="#{null}"/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{eventTypeBean.selectItems}" var="eventType"
            itemLabel="#{eventType.eventTypeName}" itemValue="#{eventType}" />

    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

This is the part from the Converter class, where it fails:

```
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) {
        if (value == null) {
                        return null; 
        }
...
```

It event did not show me the message "Please, select item!", when no element is selected. It treats the first one, as NULL and i don't know how to get rid of it. I appreciate any help.

Comment: It can work without any converter.

Comment: I did not manage to make it work without converter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made method **getAsString** to return "":

```
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) {
        if (value == null) {
                        return ""; 
        }
```

and put logic in the Java class not to write in DB when the property is empty.